# creating multiple JUnitXml reports

Tags: javascript, xml, junit, jasmine, var

i am using protractor and jasmine to run automation tests on a website.

I have three test specs running one after the other in a single suite

eg:

```
suites{
r = ['t1.js', 't2.js', 't3.js']

}
```

All three are run four times with different parameters.

Is there a way to generate consolidated JUnitXmlReports separately for these four cases?

The code below generates separate reports for one run but overwrites them in the second run.

```
var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({savePath:'tmp/xmls', filePrefix: 'junit-', consolidateAll:false}));
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I am using Jenkins as the build server so JUnitXml is needed.